# The closure of a subspace of a normed vector space is a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

This is a self-study problem (Folland *Real Analysis* exercise 5.5).

> If $\mathcal{X}$ is a normed vector space, the closure of any subspace of $\mathcal{X}$ is a subspace.

My attempt:

It is evident that $0 \in \overline{\mathcal{M}}$. Let $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{X}$ and consider $v,w \in \overline{\mathcal{M}}$. As $v$ is a limit point, there is some sequence $\{v_n\} \to v$ in the metric induced by the norm; namely for some $N$, $\|v_n - v\| \le \frac{\epsilon}{2}$ for $n \ge N$, and likewise for $w$.

Then, for scalars $a,b$, $$\|av_n+bw_n - (av + bw)\| = \|av_n - av + bw_n - bw\| \le |a|\|v_n - v\| + |b|\|w_n - w\| = \epsilon(|a|+|b|).$$

Therefore, $\mathcal{M} \supset \{av_n+bw_n\} \to av+bw$, so $av+bw \in \overline{\mathcal{M}}$.

**My question:** Is my proof correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is quite elegant. I was working on the same problem from Folland and came up with a different solution, so I thought I'd share it.

---

It is well known from topology that $\overline{\mathcal{M}}=\text{int}(\mathcal{M})\dot{\cup} \partial \mathcal{M}$.

**Case I:** $\text{int}(\mathcal{M})$ is non empty.

In this case, take $y\in \text{int}(\mathcal{M})$, that means we have a ball with radius $\varepsilon$ such that $y\in B_y(\varepsilon)\subset \mathcal{M}$.

For any $z\in \mathcal{X}$, we have that for $R$ sufficiently large, $\frac{z}{R}+y\in B_y(\varepsilon)\subset \mathcal{M}$. Hence, $z\in \mathcal{M}$ and $\mathcal{M}=\mathcal{X}$ which means $\overline{\mathcal{M}}=\mathcal{X}$.

**Case II:** $\text{int}(\mathcal{M})$ is empty.

Because $\text{int}(\mathcal{M})$ is empty, $\overline{\mathcal{M}}=\partial \mathcal{M}$. Take $x,y\in \partial M$. If we consider $U=B_{x+\lambda y}(\varepsilon)$ for $\lambda \not=0$, we note that because $x$ and $y$ are in $\partial{M}$ there exist $m_1$ and $m_2$ with:

$$m_1\in B_x(\varepsilon/2)\cap \mathcal{M} \quad,\quad m_2\in B_y(\varepsilon/(2|\lambda|))\cap \mathcal{M}$$

Because of triangle inequality $m_1+\lambda m_2\in U$ and so $U \cap \mathcal{M}\not=\emptyset$.

If $U\cap M^C=\emptyset$, $x+\lambda y$ would be an interior point for $\mathcal{M}$ which is absurd as we are in **case II**. Hence, $U\cap M^C \not=\emptyset$ and $x+\lambda y \in \partial M$.